# Lubuntu: devmon mounts an USB drive to two different directories, one of which is inaccessible

Tags: usb, mount, lubuntu, usb-drive, nas

I have formatted a 2TB Kingston SSD USB drive in EXT4 filesystem and copied data on computer A (Ubuntu). Now I want to use this drive on computer B (Lubuntu).
But it showed that the drive was mounted to two paths: `/media/devmon/Kingston` and `/media/username/Kingston`:

[image]

I can click to open the path `/media/username/Kingston` and access the data in the drive, but not through `/media/devmon/Kingston`. When clicking the latter, it showed an error:

> The specified directory '/media/devmon/Kingston' is not valid

[image]

What is going on here? What do I need to do to fix this?

When using a USB drive of 1G size with NTFS filesystem, everything went smooth. (as `/media/username/Data_Exchan` shown in the 1st pic).

---

One thing I should mention is that I have CasaOS installed in the system. It seems CasaOS has installed `udevil` and has taken control the mounting of USB drives more or less.  Maybe the default mounting utility in Lubuntu (not sure which package it is) was also working, causing two mounted directories.

Comment: You may be right about Casa OS. I don't know what that is.